# What is the correct way to pass touches through a view to those below it?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI view that is displayed over other views, and have found that using `Color.clear` like this below seems to allow touch interactions to pass through to anything under it:

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            SomeCustomContent()
            Spacer()
        }
        .overlay(GeometryReader { proxy in
            Color.clear.preference(key: MyCustomHeightPreferenceKey.self, value: proxy.size.height)
        })
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to make touches pass through to the views below, or it this just a coincidental quirk/bug in SwiftUI behaviour that Apple might fix/change as swiftui matures?

If not, what is the correct way to pass the touches through?

Comment: Touches always fall through transparent parts (Color.clear is transparent). Also you can specify explicitly on view `allowsHitTesting(false)` so it does not capture touches.

Comment: On the view you want to touch add the .onTapGesture{}, add an @State private var touched:Bool, and add a property in another view that you want to change.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can pass through touch events without using a clear color like this:

```swift
var body: some View {
    Rectangle()
        .overlay(
            Circle()
                .fill(.blue)
                .allowsHitTesting(false) // <--- Passes through gestures
        )
}
```

Asperi mentioned this solution in a comment above, and you can also find a good blog about this topic here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/disabling-user-interactivity-with-allowshittesting